# Javascript function working in JSFiddle, but not working when I copy it on my local page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is working on [http://jsfiddle.net/4zxgshpq/ ] (I have Edited) but when I copy the whole code and run it on my page did not work. I have searched for answers like moving a javascript at the end or adding $(function(){ at the beginning but it still does not work and I couldn't find any solutions. Can some one please help. Thank you.

This is my Script

```
$(function(){
$("#Units").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
   $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
   $(":checkbox[name='4[]']").change(function(){
  if ($(":checkbox[name='4[]']:checked").length == 1){                                             
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);   
  }else{                                                   
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false); 
  }
});
  }
  if ($(this).val() == "Finance") {
   $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
   $(":checkbox[name='4[]']").change(function(){
  if ($(":checkbox[name='4[]']:checked").length == 2){                                              
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);  
  }else{                                                     
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
  }
  if ($(this).val() == "Operations") {
   $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
   $(":checkbox[name='4[]']").change(function(){
  if ($(":checkbox[name='4[]']:checked").length == 3){                                              
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);  
  }else{                                                     
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
  }
  $("p").click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
    });
}).trigger('change');
});
```

-- While my index page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Checkbox inside a Dropdown based on another Dropdown Option Menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
  .multiselect {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .selectBox {
    position: relative;
  }

  .selectBox select {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .overSelect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  #checkboxes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px gold solid;
  }

  #checkboxes label {
    display: flex;
  }

  #checkboxes label:hover {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
  }

</style>
<select id="Units">
  <option value="Marketing"> Marketing </option>
  <option value="Finance"> Finance </option>
  <option value="Operations"> Operations </option>
</select>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <p style = "cursor:pointer">
      Uncheck All</p>
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "1" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="1" /> chbx1</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "2" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="2" /> chbx2</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "3" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="3" /> chbx3</label>
      <label for="four">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "4" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="4" /> chbx4</label>
        <label for="five">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "5" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="5" /> chbx5</label>
        <label for="six">
        <input type="checkbox" id = "6" class="dissable" name="4[]" onclick="check();" value="6" /> chbx6</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var expanded = false;

  function showCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    if (!expanded) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "block";
      expanded = true;
    } else {
      checkboxes.style.display = "none";
      expanded = false;
    }
  }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Thanks for having time for this. Have a good day to you .

Comment: are there errors in the console?

Comment: You don't really seem to load jquery (only the combobox part). Could it be you selected that in your fiddle, and forgot to add it in your own code?

Comment: When putting "does not work", please provide details such as console errors or "blank page", or *anything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery, but not loading it.

Add the following before your script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works on jsfiddle because it is adding the jQuery script for you as seen in the following screenshot

[image: JSFiddle framework selection]

If you don't want to use a cdn, you may obtain a local copy of jquery via [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/download/) and put it in your source "js" directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have only included the dropdown.js file, not jquery.js so your browser has no idea what the dollar symbol is. You probably see at least one TypeError in the console. Remember with jsfiddle it's as easy as selecting your desired version from a dropdown menu but in your project you need to either download the latest jquery version or include it via a Content Delivery Network:

Check this: http://jquery.com/download/ and find the method that suits your project more